# Scale down xlarge app on large Nexus 7 screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

*I know the best way of supporting different screen sizes in Android is to create different layouts for the different screen sizes.*

I know it is possible to have a phone app scale up to the tabled sized screens. What I want to know if it is possible to scale **down** my *res/layout-xlarge-land* layouts to fit the Nexus 7. I have put the following in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false" 
    android:normalScreens="false" 
    android:largeScreens="false" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But the Nexus 7 still expects the layouts in the *res/layout-large* folder, it doesn't take the layouts in the *res/layout-xlarge-land* folder. When I copy the *res/layout-xlarge-land* folder to the *res/layout-large* folder, it doesn't scale down.

I tried all kinds of different options in the manifest, but I couldn't get it to work. Is scaling down at all possible?

Edit:

I know the proper way is to create the `large` layout for the Nexus 7 and then create specific layouts for that device. But I'm working on a schedule and I can't influence the design (which is designed for a 10-inch tablet). So I am forced for the 7-inch tablets to use the phone design.

I know that Android Phone-only apps can be made to scale up to fit larger screens if specified in the manifest. So I was wondering if the other way around would work, where the 10-inch layouts are scaled down to fit the 7-inch screen (much like apps for the iPad scale down on the iPad Mini). I got the feeling from reading this article (http://www.tested.com/tech/android/1381-how-android-scales-apps-for-different-screen-sizes)  that this was possible, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: "When I copy the res/layout-xlarge-land folder to the res/layout-large folder, it doesn't scale down" -- what does this statement mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of misconceptions in your development process.

First off, Android will not "scale down" a layout for you. You have to do that yourself and then provide the size-appropriate layouts in the specific folders. An `xlarge` layout may contain more UI elements than a `large` layout, just like a `land` layout may arrange elements differently than its portrait counterpart. If you just copy the layouts from one folder to another, then there's really no need for all those specifiers, is there?

Secondly, the Nexus 7 is a `large` device, not `xlarge` as you seem to think. The Nexus 10 is `xlarge`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize this is the proper way to do it, I was just wondering if there was an "easy way out" to still have the 10-inch tablet design on a 7-inch tablet until I got the time to do the proper `large` layouts. See my edit.

Comment: Nope, sorry -- you'll have to do it the hard (proper) way, or design your layouts to be scalable by using layout_weight instead of dip sizes.